# add text file to subversion repository-- that it thinks is binary

Tags: svn

I'm trying to add a text file to SVN and it has different ideas.  Using tortoise SVN and right clicking "Add.." I get an unhappy message telling me the file has a binary mime type property.  And it won't add it to the repository.

I can't think of why that would be, as it's one of several text files (SQL stored procedure listings in this case) that I created at once.  (Three files, in fact, give me this message, while two others were added just fine.)

When I tried changing the mime property on the file via `svn propset svn:mime-type text/plain` I'm given a warning that the file isn't under version control, which is of course 100% true.

What can I do to get SVN to recognize these files as text, and add them to the repository?

Comment: What's the extension of the file?

Comment: .PRC is the extension on all five of the files.

Comment: What are you using for a Subversion client, or are you using a command line interface to modify Subversion?

Comment: You might be confusing Subversion.  Here are 4 file types that use the PRC extension.  http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/prc

Comment: You could try checking the line endings of the suspect files versus the ones that added just fine using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) or your preferred text editor. I would also check if they are ANSI or UTF-8 or something else, which is causing SVN to treat them as binary.

Comment: @Gilbert-- I use Tortoise SVN for my checkins and adds.

Comment: What's odd is that I tried to add five .PRC files, and two of them went in-- the other three did not.  I copied/pasted the contents of the three files into three new ones (using Notepad++, as I always do) and then they were added successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the following steps (using TortoiseSVN) to check what is the source of the failure:

- Open your `TortoiseSVN > Settings`, and open there `General > Subversion configuration file > Edit`.
- Search in that file for the string `"prc"` (without double quotes).
- If you find a rule like that: `*.prc = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream`, this is the reason that the property is added.
- There is no way that the `autoprops` come from another source (see [Subversion wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/subversion/Inheritable-Ignores-AutoProps) for details).
- Just to be sure: Do you have client hooks installed? This is the only thing I can think of that does that for you.
- If all fails, ask your Subversion administrator if there is a server hook (like a pre-commit hook), that 1. sets the property and 2. checks the property. But this sounds ridiculous.

Try to do the following steps:

1. Add a file `test.prc` (with some content) to your directory (a local copy).
2. Use `TortoiseSVN > Add` on that file.
3. Open then the properties for that file. If there are properties, there should be the autoprops in your configuration, or a hook that changes the props.
4. If there are no properties (what should be normal), try to commit that file to the server.
5. If that works well now, ...
6. Check the properties of that file again (they could have changed).

By the way, some information about your Subversion server version, TortoiseSVN client version would be helpful ...

Comment: thank you for the configuration checking steps.  I looked at the config file as you asked and the only "prc" mention is for the line breaks (svn:eol-style=CRLF).
When I added the test.prc to the SVN repository, the only properties on it were for the eol-style line break as above.  My Tortoise version is 1.6.10, from 2010, so it's a bit out of date, but works fine generally.

Answer (score 2):

I had this once with a resource.h file generated by VS2013.

I opened the file in an editor and changed the Coding from "UCS-2 LE BOM" to UTF-8.

Sometimes it's very easy